# How I make live video chat for my website

Tags: webrtc

I want to add video chat option in my website please guide me how i do this task and what should i required for doing this.How much it's cost if i will make it for my website and also it's maintenance(Like server ETC).

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: Thanks Bro but what i need for this should i want to but any expensive server or else

Comment: you already have hosting? On client side JavaScript, but for signaling you need server side, for example SignalR or node.js

Comment: you can look at my site: https://signalrtc.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like [rtchub.com](https://rtchub.com/)

Comment: How i developed it  using PHP and webRTC. Thanks for responce

Comment: Step 1 - Login or create RTChub account. Step 2 - Copy the widget html and paste it into your website. Step 3 - Start your website and click video call button. Step 4 - You will recieve call notification, accept the call

Comment: But it's to expensive for initial and it's free for only one month

Comment: What do you mean. It cost ten bucks per month

Answer (score 0):

If you want it free, you can develop it yourself, using [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/):

> WebRTC is a free, open project that provides browsers and mobile
>   applications with Real-Time Communications (RTC) capabilities via
>   simple APIs. The WebRTC components have been optimized to best serve
>   this purpose.

See [WebRTC Tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

On client side you use JavaScript (jQuery), and clients communication directly using browser, but you need server part and signaling mechanism, and you can use for example [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) or [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

As example you can look at my site: [SignalRTC](https://signalrtc.com/).

P.S. WebRTC works only on selected browsers, for example Chrome, FireFox, unfortunately not on IE or Edge.

Comment: SO it has any alternative to run in IE or Edge

Comment: using WebRTC - no, alternatives - use some browser's plugin or flash or silverlight.